# How to show 'id' inside the scattered plot (python matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show the appropriate ID (integer) in each of the scattered plots. The plots are placed inside a 3D plot but whatever I try I can't seem to get this to work. Can anyone help me?

```
def generate_3d_plot(spawn_points, minmax_x, minmax_y, minmax_z, output_filename, map_id):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 7), dpi=300)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.view_init(elev=25, azim=45)
    for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(spawn_points):
        ax.text(x, y, z, f"{i+1}", color='white', ha='center', va='center', fontsize=12)
        ax.scatter(x, y, z, color='black', s=150)
    ax.set_xlim(*minmax_x)
    ax.set_ylim(*minmax_y)
    ax.set_zlim(*minmax_z)
    ax.grid(True, which='both', ls="--", linewidth=0.5, color='grey')
    ax.set_axisbelow(False)
    plt.savefig(output_filename, bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()
```

Right now the plotting works, the graph is created, but there are no id's inside the plots.

Right now the plotting works, the graph is created, but there are no id's inside the plots.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your scatter is shown over your text.
A solution is to specify that you want the text on top of the scatter, via the `zorder` keyword (see [zorder demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html)).

You can do something like

```
ax.text(x, y, z, f"{i+1}", color='white', ha='center', va='center', fontsize=12, zorder=spawn_points.size)
```

It specifies that all the texts are shown on top of all the scatter dots.
I assumed you `spawn_points` was a numpy array, otherwise just put zorder greater than the number of points and you will obtain the desired result.